# print a date and time in command window MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I use matlab R2015a, when I run my script I want print the date and the time of exection

I tried this code

```
Dtimes=datetime('now','TimeZone','local','Format','d-MMM-y HH:mm:ss Z');
% the first test
disp(' Date and time is ' Dtimes ); % But not work
% second test
disp(sprintf('date and time is %s  ',Dtimes)) %also not work
```

But with this command is worked :

```
disp(sprintf('date and time is %s  ',datestr(now)));
```

What is the problem?

Comment: How is that connected with signal processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While significantly off topic, this one is easy: Dtimes is datetime object and not a string. What would work is

```
display(Dtimes)
disp([' Date and time is ' char(Dtimes)] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Mathworks' documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html), `datetime` returns an array, not a string. Therefore, you cannot use disp to display a string `Date and time is` together with that returned array.

Your second method is also not working because again Dtimes is an array and you cannot use `%s` to print it.

Your last method is working because `datestr` returns a string [see documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html?searchHighlight=datestr).

Please let me know if this explanation is not clear/enough.